# Subscribe to be emailed about Steam games being on sale at 50%+ discount?

Tags: steam

Is there any way to subscribe to receive emails about Steam games offered at 50% or higher discount?

Comment: write a program that checks the website periodically and sends you an email when it founds new games at 50% if you need advice on how to write such program go to stackoverflow.com   =)

Comment: @Luiscencio I already write programs to do that sort of stuff. Lately I have been doing nothing more than scratching my own itches like that, for weeks on end. I probably have more than 20 itch-scratching proggies I made for myself. This madness has got to stop, I have to write code for money too inbetween things like this one! (Oh yeah, and play those games I buy :D)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i think this site could help.

http://www.steamwatch.com/

Apparently you can register and if some games go on sale you get notified by e-mail. ;)

Have fun.

Answer (score 7):

You can register to Steam Forums and sign to receive notifications for the following thread answers: [Steam Deals and Price Reductions!](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=518670)

Comment: Whoa, looks like a catch-all thread for discussing pretty much everything :) Can I subscribe to posts by a specific user?

Comment: Unfortunately not, it's a bit spamming I know, but you are sure to be updated daily on all sales and price reductions.

Answer (score 3):

I follow [@steamydeals](https://twitter.com/#!/steamydeals) on Twitter. It's inofficial, but it does a good job of capturing all the offers and pricedrops, one per tweet, including the new price and the reduction, and including a link to the store page.

That's *all* offers and pricedrops, though, not just those with 50%+.

There are (3rdparty) tools for getting new tweets by mail, but I don't know much about them.